# apt remove xscreensaver removes lubuntu-desktop and installs many new packages

Tags: ubuntu, apt, lubuntu, lxde, xscreensaver

Upon running

```
sudo apt remove xscreensaver
```

I am prompted with the below messages.  Is this normal?  Should I proceed?  Why would removing a screensaver involve so many things?  I'm using LXDE desktop, by the way, can I safely remove `lubuntu-desktop`?

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas activity-log-manager apg aptdaemon-data cheese-common dconf-cli evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-faces gnome-online-accounts gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver
  gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common gnome-startup-applications gnome-user-docs
  gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 ibus ibus-data ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 indicator-applet indicator-application
  indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-common indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power
  indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound jayatana language-selector-gnome libaccounts-glib0 libbamf3-2 libcamel-1.2-62
  libcanberra-pulse libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
  libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcolord-gtk1 libdee-1.0-4 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20
  libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-24 libedataserverui-1.2-2
  libgee-0.8-2 libgeoclue-2-0 libgeocode-glib0 libgeonames-common libgeonames0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-panel0 libgnomekbd-common
  libgnomekbd8 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgsound0 libgssdp-1.2-0 libgtop-2.0-11 libgtop2-common libgupnp-1.2-0 libgupnp-av-1.0-2
  libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libgweather-3-16 libgweather-common libibus-1.0-5 libido3-0.1-0 libindicator3-7 liblightdm-gobject-1-0
  libmediaart-2.0-0 libmessaging-menu0 libphonenumber7 libprotobuf17 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2
  librygel-server-2.6-2 libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0
  libunity-settings-daemon1 liburl-dispatcher1 libwhoopsie-preferences0 libxklavier16 libzeitgeist-2.0-0 light-locker
  light-locker-settings lightdm mousetweaks nautilus-data python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-ibus-1.0 python3-macaroonbakery
  python3-protobuf python3-psutil python3-rfc3339 python3-tz rygel session-migration ubuntu-docs ubuntu-system-service
  ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-control-center unity-greeter unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module
  unity-settings-daemon unity-settings-daemon-schemas whoopsie-preferences zeitgeist-core
Suggested packages:
  evolution gnome-software | gnome-packagekit gnome-user-share realmd libcanberra-gtk-module usbguard ibus-clutter ibus-doc
  unity-greeter-session-broadcast url-dispatcher bindfs python-psutil-doc gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly rygel-playbin
  rygel-preferences rygel-ruih rygel-tracker tumbler zeitgeist-datahub
Recommended packages:
  appmenu-qt systemd-services
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  lubuntu-desktop xscreensaver
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas activity-log-manager apg aptdaemon-data cheese-common dconf-cli evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-faces gnome-online-accounts gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver
  gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common gnome-startup-applications gnome-user-docs
  gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 ibus ibus-data ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 indicator-applet indicator-application
  indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-common indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power
  indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound jayatana language-selector-gnome libaccounts-glib0 libbamf3-2 libcamel-1.2-62
  libcanberra-pulse libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
  libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcolord-gtk1 libdee-1.0-4 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20
  libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-24 libedataserverui-1.2-2
  libgee-0.8-2 libgeoclue-2-0 libgeocode-glib0 libgeonames-common libgeonames0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-panel0 libgnomekbd-common
  libgnomekbd8 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgsound0 libgssdp-1.2-0 libgtop-2.0-11 libgtop2-common libgupnp-1.2-0 libgupnp-av-1.0-2
  libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libgweather-3-16 libgweather-common libibus-1.0-5 libido3-0.1-0 libindicator3-7 liblightdm-gobject-1-0
  libmediaart-2.0-0 libmessaging-menu0 libphonenumber7 libprotobuf17 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2
  librygel-server-2.6-2 libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0
  libunity-settings-daemon1 liburl-dispatcher1 libwhoopsie-preferences0 libxklavier16 libzeitgeist-2.0-0 light-locker
  light-locker-settings lightdm mousetweaks nautilus-data python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-ibus-1.0 python3-macaroonbakery
  python3-protobuf python3-psutil python3-rfc3339 python3-tz rygel session-migration ubuntu-docs ubuntu-system-service
  ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-control-center unity-greeter unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module
  unity-settings-daemon unity-settings-daemon-schemas whoopsie-preferences zeitgeist-core
0 upgraded, 136 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 40.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 144 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

Comment: According to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/i6rc6o/how_to_safely_disable_or_remove_xscreensaver_on/) that might be the correct behavior and will not affect anything. But I'm not sure if that is totally true since they did not mention about the installation of new packages (and the thread was posted 2 year ago)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Yes, I saw that too, but in my case apt is explicitly saying it will remove `lubuntu-desktop` and installing many new packages....

Comment: Are you on VM? If you are not you can try installing your current os in a VM and try to remove `xscreensaver`. According to reddit post `lubuntu-desktop` is a meta package that contains nothing. But in your case seems to replace `lubuntu-desktop` by `gnome-desktop` (because of the new packages to install)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon  It may take some time for me to set up the VM.  In the meantime I'd just turn off `xscreensaver`.  I suspect it's affecting my mouse settings even when turned off.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hopefully someone has a solution  here! :). You can also ask in another forum (related to ubuntu/lubuntu) or  maybe to `xscreensaver` (xdg-utils) developers.

Comment: Xscreensaver is not affecting my mouse -- my mouse wire is faulty.  But the remove problem is still here, though not urgent.  I'll update when I find out more :)

Comment: Nice! maybe that problem (could be a bug with some package) has a solution in some days or maybe that's the default behavior of removing that package.

Comment: `xscreensaver` is one of the packages `lubuntu-desktop` depends on. Whatever you're trying to achieve, do not remove `lubuntu-desktop` and try to solve the issue another way, not by removing a crucial package.